# vue.js pass data to route using beforeRouteUpdate

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

vue.js I am trying to pass data from route to app.vue ,
         I am relying on **beforeRouteUpdate**
what I am trying to do is

```
    routes: [
      {
          path: '/dashboard',
          name: 'dashboard',
          component: function () {  return import( './views/dashboard.vue')  },

          beforeRouteUpdate: (to, from, next) => { document.title = 'dashboard';  next(); }
      },
        {
          path: '/home',
          name: 'home',
          component: function () {  return import( './views/home.vue')  },

          beforeRouteUpdate: (to, from, next) => { document.title = 'home';  next(); }
        },
```

*document.title* is working put it's not dynmaic in the app.vue ,
 what i mean is when i choose anther  route *document.title* does not change in the *app.vue*

in app.vue

```
data(){
  return { 
    getselected :  document.title, 
  }
},
mounted() {
    console.log('getselected  - '+ this.getselected );
},
```

Comment: So if you add a watch on "getselected", it's value doesn't change?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the function `beforeRouteUpdate` is a component hook. Then, you can't use this inside your router. But you can pass a param to your route, via query.

Your router:

```
routes: [
      {
          path: '/dashboard',
          name: 'dashboard',
          query: {title: 'dashboard'},
          component: function () {  return import( './views/dashboard.vue')  }, 
      },
        {
          path: '/home',
          name: 'home',
          query: {title: 'home'},
          component: function () {  return import( './views/home.vue')  },
        },
]
```

Your component:

```
data(){
  return { 
    documentTitle:  '', 
  }
},
mounted() {
    this.documentTitle = this.$route.query.title;
},
```

In other way, you can use your path name inside your component. You even don't need to declare `query` in your router.

```
data(){
  return { 
    documentTitle:  '', 
  }
},
mounted() {
    this.documentTitle = this.$route.path.name;
},
```

Comment: beforeRouteUpdate is a component hook, but beforeEnter could also be used - https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#per-route-guard